# How to find the UMPT for Gamma distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, maximum-likelihood, inference, gamma-distribution

I have the gamma distribution given by;
$$f_{\theta} (x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\theta)} x^{\theta -1} e^{-x}; x > 0 , \theta > 0$$ How can I obtain a UMPT for this function? 
I have tried using the LRT but I simply can't obtain MLE estimates. How can I go about it (possibly using another approach or this very one)?

Comment: Is it a simple hypothesis that you want to test?

Comment: I think he wants a humpty dumpty function